# parsing csv file in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

i have task
Need to update column name.
Name format: first letter of name/surname uppercase and all other letters lowercase.
Need to update column email with domain @abc.
Email format: first letter from name and full surname, lowercase.
Equals emails should contain location_id.
Sripts should has name task1.sh
Path to accounts.csv file should be as argument to the script.
Definition of done.
Developed bash script which automatically creates accounts_new.csv and updates columns name and
email based on the rules above.

i create script

```
`#!/bin/bash

# Check if input file is provided
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <input_file>"
    exit 1
fi

input_file="$1"
output_file="accounts_new.csv"

capitalize () {
    local sep=''
    local field
    for field in "$@"; do
        field=${field,,}
        printf "%s%s" "$sep" "${field^}"
        sep=' '
    done
    printf '\n'
}

name2e () {
    local fname=${1,,}
    printf '%s%s\n' "${fname:0:1}" "${2,,}"
}

get_duplicates () {
    cut -d, -f3 "$1" |
    sed 's/^\([^ ]\)[^ ]* /\1/' |
    tr A-Z a-z |
    sort |
    uniq -d
}

duplicates=$(get_duplicates "$input_file")
# A single newline in a string
nl='
'

first=true
while read -r line; do
    case $first in
        true) echo "$line"; first=false; continue;;
    esac
    for field in id location_id name; do
        printf -v "$field" '%s' "${line%%,*}"
        line=${line#"${!field}",}
    done
    for field in email department; do
        printf -v "$field" '%s' "${line##*,}"
        line=${line%",${!field}"}
    done
    case $email in
        '')
            email="$(name2e $name)";;
    esac
    case $nl$duplicates$nl in
        *"$nl$email$nl"*)
            email=$email$location_id;;
    esac
    case $line in
        *,*) title="$line";;
        *) title="$line";;
    esac
    printf "%i,%i,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" \
           "$id" "$location_id" "$(capitalize $name)" \
           "$title" "$email@abc.com" "$department"
done <"$input_file" > "$output_file"

echo "Output written to $output_file"
`
```

the script runs almost successfully except for some lines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoZep.png)

Comment: Don't use a shell read loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).